# Is there a direct proof that $\mathcal O(n) \in \text{thick}_{D^b(\mathbb P^1)}\{\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1)\} $ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $\mathbb P^1$ denote $\mathbb P^1_k$. Let $D^b(\mathbb P^1)$ be the bounded Derived Category of Coherent Sheaves on $\mathbb P^1$. Let $\text{thick}_{D^b(\mathbb P^1)}\{\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1)\}$ be the intersection of all thick subcategories ( https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thick+subcategory)  of $D^b(\mathbb P^1)$ containing $\mathcal O$ and  $\mathcal O(1)$.

Is there a direct proof (without going into semiorthogonal decomposition) of the fact that for every $n\in \mathbb Z$, we have $\mathcal O(n) \in \text{thick}_{D^b(\mathbb P^1)}\{\mathcal O, \mathcal O(1)\} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n > 0$ there are exact sequences
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus (n-1)} \to \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus n} \to \mathcal{O}(n) \to 0
$$
and
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(-n) \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus (n+1)} \to \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus n} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please let me know the maps in the exact sequences? (I would like to understand why it only holds for projective line, and not for higher dimensional projective spaces...)

Comment: Let me explain the first sequence. The second map is the row $$(x^{n-1},x^{n-2}y,\dots,xy^{n-2},y^{n-2}).$$ The first map is a matrix with $n-1$ columns, with the $i$-th column having the form $$(0,\dots,0,y,-x,0,\dots,0)$$ with $i-1$ zeroes at the beginning and $n-i-1$ zeroes at the end.

Comment: Hello ... I just stumbled upon this question ... could you please explain the maps in the second short exact sequence? Thanks

Comment: The second sequence is dual to the first (up to twist, and change of $n$), so the maps in it are transposed to the maps in the first sequence.